# CFSG-free proof for classifying simple $K_3$-group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, classification

Let $G$ be a finite nonabelian simple group.
We call $G$ a $K_3$-group if $|G|=p^aq^br^c$ where $p,q,r$ are distinct primes and $a,b,c$ are positive integers.

**My question is: Is there a CFSG-free proof of the classification of simple $K_3$-groups?**

Any explanation, references, suggestion and examples are appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I have already corrected the typos. Thanks. @LSpice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the Feit-Thompson theorem, one of the primes has to be two. Then by John Thompson's N-group classification (1970-1973), the three primes have to come from a very short list of triples. The various cases were then worked out by Geoff Mason, David Wales, and Jeff Leon in the seventies. This should give you enough information to get the references from MR.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. However, I read this sentence at the page 14 of "Finite simple groups-an introduction to their classification" by D. Gorenstein. It says ""However, simple (2,3,5)- and (2,3,7)-groups were never fully treated as independent problems." Since the book was written in 80s, I am wondering if there is a new proof. @Dave Benson

Comment: I'm pretty sure nobody has really tried since then, because the problem was overtaken by the classification.  What exists is by the authors I named.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sometimes, one might meet some problems only requires the classification of $K_3$-group. So, I expect a CFSG-free proof : )  Thanks very much for your explanation. @Dave Benson